# Help me define an optimization problem in formal Mathematic terms/conventions?

Tags: optimization, word-problem

I have an optimization problem which I can explain in words; but I am attempting to define it mathematically to make it more easily understood (by those who know math better than I).

I have a function which determines how much experience is required to reach the next level:

`To_Reach_Next_Level = floor(To_Reach_Next_Level(Current_Level-1) * 1.01)` where `Level_0 = 500`

another function which determines the amount of experience given (*and includes a reference to the previous function*):

`Experience_Gained = To_Reach_Next_Level(Current_Level+1) * G * (1.0 - (Current_Level - J) / K)`

`G`, `J`, and `K` all come from sets of numbers similar to:

`{ { G=0.3, J=1, K=25 }, { G=0.6, J=5, K=50 } }`
This set of numbers is much longer than just 2 points - somewhere between 40-100. Each "point" has an inherent "cost" which is 0 or greater. These points and cost are the "unknown" of the equation - and differ from one problem to the next.

My goal is to find a set of points from those given that minimizes `cost` while gaining enough `experience` to reach Level 400. Note that the same point can be applied multiple times.

there are a set of constraints, which I'm not sure whether they can affect the optimization or not:

`1.0 <= Current_Level <= 400`
`1.0 <= J <= Current_Level`
`0.3 <= L <= 1.85`
`25 <= K <= 250`

---

The example:

At level 0, it requires 500 experience to reach level 1.
At level 1, it requires 505 experience to reach level 2 (Experience at level 0 * 1.01)...
At level 59, it requires 864 experience to reach level 60.

The experience given from point `{ G=0.6, J=50, K=25 }` where Current_Level is 59 is...
`Exp_Gained = To_Reach_Next_Level(Current_Level+1) * G * (1.0 - (Current_Level - J) / K)`
`Exp_Gained = 864 * 0.6 * (1.0 - (59-50)/25) = 332`

**My primary question: How do I restate this problem in a more mathematically concise and clear way?**

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by "Current_Level-1". I suggest defining $x_n$ to be the experience from level $n$ to $n+1$, with $x_1=500$ and $x_{n+1}=\lfloor1.01x_n\rfloor$. However this gives $x_{59}=856$ and $x_{60}=864$, inconsistent with your example.

Comment: @stewbasic Apologies, I came across the same inconsistency from my source and decided they must mean that Level 0 = 500 (*due to how some of the other example values line up*), but forgot to address that when creating this question. Otherwise you seem to be correct - the first function given has some recursion.

Comment: Also you probably need to clarify what happens to excess experience when a new level is reached; is it retained and counted towards the next level? (eg what happens if I'm level 1 with 480 experience and gain 800 experience?)

Comment: @stewbasic It is retained and counted towards next level. At level 400 I should have a total of 2,396,677 experience